# Min and max of a two variables function

Tags: real-analysis

> I consider the function
>   $$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \
> (x,y) \mapsto \max\left(1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2},2-\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2},0\right).$$
>   I have to find $\max$ and $\min$ (local and global).

I calculate where $1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2-\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2}$ is an ellipse but I don't understand how find $\max$ and $\min$.

Comment: I would guess that the point is break the plane into regions so that in each region only one function is max throughout. One is the ellipse, but note that $0$ option. You will also have two circles. These may intersect with the ellipse to form more regions. So find and define the regions, and specify which function is max (or min) in each of them. You can test a point in each to find out which is max and which is min.

Comment: I'm in $R^2$ so i have two circles: one with C1=(0,0) and r=1 and one with C2=(6,0) and r=2. In $R^2-\{C1,C2\}$ the function is null.If i consier the restriction of f to the circles i have that the function has value 1 or 2.I have to study the internal of the circles?

Comment: The functions are defined everywhere in the plane, but differing functions are maximum depending on where you are in the circles. I've posted a complete work-up of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > 0$ inside a circle of radius $1$ about the origin, and is $< 0$ outside that circle. Meanwhile $2-\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2} > 0$ inside a circle of radius $2$ about the point $(6, 0)$ and is $< 0$ outside. Since the centers of these circles are a distance of $6$ apart while the sum of the radii is only $3$. So these circles are disjoint.

Ergo, outside both circles and on the circles themselves, $0$ is the maximum. Inside the circle about $(0,0), 1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is the maximum. Inside the circle about $(6, 0), 2-\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2}$ is the maximum.

The minimum problem is more difficult. Since for any point one of the two functions is negative, $0$ is never the minimum. Now connect any point where $1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} <2-\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2}$ to any point where $1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} >2-\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2}$ with a line segment, and by the continuity of the two functions, somewhere along that line segment the two functions are equal. Thus if we identify where the two functions are equal, that curve will divide the plane into regions where either one or the other is less.
$$1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 2-\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2}\\
\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2} = 1 + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
x^2-12x + 36+y^2 = 1 + x^2 + y^2 + 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
35 - 12x = 2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
1225 - 840x + 144x^2 = 4x^2 + 4y^2\\
140(x^2 - 6x + 9) - 4y^2 = (9)(140) - 1225\\
140(x - 3)^2 - 4y^2 = 35$$
So the two functions are equal on a hyperbola. But note that the calculation isn't reversable. So not every point on the hyperbola may be a place the two functions are equal. In particular, when $y = 0$, we get that $|x - 3| = 1/2$
Now $$1 - \sqrt{2.5^2 + 0^2} = -1.5\\2-\sqrt{(2.5-6)^2+0^2} = -1.5$$ but $$1 - \sqrt{3.5^2 + 0^2} = -2.5\\2-\sqrt{(3.5-6)^2+0^2} = -0.5$$
So the two functions are equal only on the arc of the hyperbola through $(2.5, 0)$. Namely when $$x = 3 - \sqrt\frac{35 - 4y^2}{140}$$

Ergo, when $x < \sqrt\frac{35 - 4y^2}{140}, 2-\sqrt{(x-6)^2+y^2}$ is minimum, when $x > \sqrt\frac{35 - 4y^2}{140}, 1 - \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is minimum, and when $x = 3 - \sqrt\frac{35 - 4y^2}{140}$, the two are equal, so either one could be taken as minimum.